# Logic behind "while True"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm still trying to understand the logic behind while loops. Below is some code that seems to work. However, I'm confused why in order for the code to run logically I must start the if statement with !=. Since I'm using "while True" wouldn't it make sense to run the if statement ==?

```
while True:
name = input("What is your username?")      # user asked to input name
if name != "prime90":                       # if name is not equal to "prime90"
    print("Invalid username!")
    continue                                # Starts the program again from the top if name is wrong
userpass = input("What is your password?")
if userpass == "password":
    print('Access Granted')
    break                                   # Stops program once the correct password is entered
else:
    print("Access Denied!!")
```

Comment: That's because I wrote the comments...I was able to get this to work but not without error/luck. At first, I wrote the first if statement with ==  because I thought since the while statement was True I should have a true if statement. Clearly, my logic is wrong because it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

While True is intended to put your code in an infinite loop, and it'll keep on repeating the code inside it unless the 'break' statement isn't executed.
So, let's see what you need to go to the break statement in the code.
Note that the accepted username is 'prime90', and the valid password is 'password'.

The code says that if the entered username is not 'prime90', the first **if** condition will get satisfied, and the code will print 'Invalid username!', and the 'continue' keyword will restart the loop, so the code will again ask 'what is your username?'.

If you enter a correct username this time, i-e if you enter 'prime90', the first **if** condition will not be satisfied, and the code will now ask you 'What is your password?'. If you enter 'password' as your password, the **if** condition below will be satisfied, the code will print 'Access Granted', and will execute the 'break' statement. And when the 'break' statement gets executed, the code will come out of the while loop.

However, if you enter a password which is something other than 'password', your second **if** condition will not be satisfied, and the program will go into the **else** block in the end, which will print 'Access Denied!!', and your while loop will start again from the beginning.

In short, if both your username and password are 'prime90' and 'password' respectively, then the code will come out of the while loop, otherwise it'll remain inside the loop forever.

Comment: Yes Syed I understand what each line of code is doing. I guess a better question is why can't I run this code properly if the first if statement is ==. My thinking is that since im using "while True"  then I would want to start out with an if statement using == and not !=. Thank you for the detailed response.